# TclOO install gives error during configure

Tags: tcl

While trying to install TclOO1.0, the ./configure gives the error

```
checking for Tcl private include files... configure: error: Cannot find private header tclInt.h in /home/chhama/tcl8.6.0
```

My intention is to build it using tcl 8.5.10 and I have no idea where the 8.6 comes from. Do I need to specify the version somewhere?

Comment: It looks as though you've got an inconsistent set of source/configuration files. 8.6 is the current version of Tcl and I guess that your `configure` file is for that version. If I were you, I'd go back to wherever I got my sources from and start again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by doing a fresh ns2 install and then installing TclOO on top of that.